# Extract numbers from a array and divide them (positives and negatives) into separate arrays

Tags: java

I want to extract numbers from an array and divide them into positives and negatives into separate arrays. Why does my Java code does not work?

How to make it work?

```
int pole[] = new int[20];
int pock = 0;
int pocz = 0;
int pocn = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < pole.length; i++) {
    pole[i] = (int)(-10+Math.random()*21);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(pole[i]>0)pock++;
    else if(pole[i]<0) pocz++;
    else pocn++;
}
int pklad[] = new int[pock];
int pzap[] = new int [pocz];
int n[] = new int [pocn];
int j = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < pole.length; i++) {
    if(pole[i]>0){
        pklad[j] = pole[i];

    }if(pole[i]<0){ 
        pzap[j] = pole[i];

    }else n[j]=pole[i];
    j++;
}
System.out.print("All positives: ");
for (int i = 0; i < pock; i++) {
    System.out.print(pklad[i]+",");
}
System.out.println();

System.out.print("All negatives: ");
for (int i = 0; i < pocz; i++) {
    System.out.println(pzap[i]);
}
System.out.print("Zeros: ");
for (int i = 0; i < pocn; i++) {
    System.out.println(n[i]);
}
```

**Edit:** This throws an exception: (thanks, [BRjava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355283/brjava))

> `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, line 36

Comment: does not work ... does it compile? does it run? is there an exception? is there just some unexpected behaviour? ...

Comment: Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve]. You don't mention the problem, in what part of the code, ...

Comment: this has an exception : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in line 36 (for loop) . fix it first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have three arrays, `pklad[]`, `pzap[]`, and `n[]`, but you try using a single index `j` to write to all three. This is what is causing your `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`: as soon as `j` goes past the limit of the shorter of the arrays, an attempted write causes the exception.

You need three separate indexes, say, `jpos`, `jneg`, and `jn`, all initialized to zero before the loop. Each index needs to be incremented individually when you write to its corresponding array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pole.length; i++) {
    if (pole[i] > 0) {
        pklad[jpos++] = pole[i];

    } else if (pole[i] < 0) { 
        pzap[jneg++] = pole[i];

    } else {
        n[jn++]=pole[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not promote those kind of question by answering it... this was an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` that was not even provided here.

Comment: @AxelH I disagree. This isn't bad at all for a first post. OP made an honest effort at the task, and got his code almost right. He also posted a follow-up comment explaining the error, so I think he completely deserves some help from the community.

Comment: I agree that the effort in the code is good. But in the question itself, there is no explanation on the problem, on what is happening, not a mention about an exception occuring. I didn't downvote the question because for a first, this is better than most question. PS: the comment is not from OP but someone that either run the code or read it. So still not explain by him.

Comment: @AxelH Oops, you're right, I didn't see who's the author of that comment. I'll edit the question to add this info. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the ArrayList it is better than normal arrays.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Double> yourNumbers = new ArrayList<Double>();
    yourNumbers.add(54.2); //add some number to our array
    yourNumbers.add(-67.7);
    ArrayList<Double> positive = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Double> negative = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Double currentNumber : yourNumbers) {
        if(currentNumber >= 0) {
            positive.add(currentNumber);
        }else if(currentNumber <0) {
            negative.add(currentNumber);
        }
    }
    //print all positive numbers
    for(Double currentDouble : positive) {
        System.out.println("Positive: "+currentDouble);
    }
    //print all negative numbers
    for(Double currentDouble : negative) {
        System.out.println("Negative: "+currentDouble);
    }
}
```